# Why are Brazil and Quebec excluded from Google's CTF competition?

Tags: united-states, internet, brazil, quebec

[Google is hosting](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/) an information security competition (a [CTF](https://ctftime.org/ctf-wtf/)) with participants from around the world.

Their participation rules from 2017 explicitly exclude residents of certain countries:

> The Contest is open to individuals who are [...] (2) not a resident of Brazil, Quebec, Cuba, Iran, Syria, North Korea, Sudan, or Crimea;

[(Source)](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/rules)

Due to US embargoes, it's plausible that Cuba, Iran, Syria, North Korea, Sudan and Crimea are excluded from the competition (which also features a monetary reward). But why are Brazil and Quebec on the list, too? The FAQ only makes a vague reference to legal difficulties:

> Why are Brazil and Quebec excluded from the CTF?
>
> Local laws and regulations make it extremely challenging for us to
> run a   competition open for residents of those locations. We are
> truly sorry about   this, and hope to change this in the future if
> possible.

[(Source)](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/faq)

Could you give some insights into what particular legal challenges might have led to the decision to exclude Brazil and Quebec from the CTF?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with gambling laws, and restrictions on what constitutes a "game of skill" for those purposes. Only a supposition without evidence, which is why this is a comment.

Comment: In support of that, https://www.thebalance.com/why-are-so-many-competitions-void-in-quebec-896835